# Saving flash Stage Data to XML (runtime)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flashdevelop, starling-framework

I am working on a prototype in which i have to generate XML file of stage, I mean to say that in which order elements created on stage i have to create node list in XML with their data type and other properties.

like I have created two movieClips on stage, then XML should be like this :

```
<root>
   <movieClip name="container">
     <width>100</width>
     <height>100</height>
     <alpha>0.5</alpha>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>0</y>
   </movieclip>

   <movieClip name="child">
     <width>200</width>
     <height>10</height>
     <alpha>1</alpha>
     <x>120</x>
     <y>50</y>
   </movieclip>
</root>
```

It is like a XML generator tool, you put data on stage and generate XML of that hierarchy. If any one have any idea how can i achieve that, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use lots of methods provided here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html

In particular look at:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()

and

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()

With lots of patience, it can be done.